# Remove multiple time intervals in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I'm using the command below to remove time intervals like time between 9:25 am and 9:35 am but its not working.

WHERE TIMEONLY NOT IN ((TIMEONLY BETWEEN '09:25:00' AND '09:35:00') OR (TIMEONLY BETWEEN '11:55:00' AND '12:05:00')
OR (TIMEONLY BETWEEN '15:10:00' AND '15:20:00'))

Any suggestions! I highly appreciate your help.

Rishabh

Comment: Why do you have the other conditions in there if you're just looking to delete between 9:25am and 9:35am? Also, are you columns stored as dates?

Comment: TIMEONLY column is in time format: "09:30:00", I need to remove time between (9:25 am and 9:35 am) and between (11:55 am and 12:05 pm) and other more intervals